# Server login attempts NOT blocked after configuring fail2ban

Tags: ubuntu, fail2ban

So, I installed (and configured) fail2ban on three Ubuntu VPS servers. I configured (imo) a maximum of 3 failed login attempts (via Putty as root) within 2 minutes. Then I restarted the fail2ban service (according to [this manual](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-ssh-with-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-12-04)).

But when I look at my `auth.log` files in `/var/log/` I still see 4, 5 or more failed attempts from certain IP's. So obviously I did something wrong as the IP is not blocked after 3 failed attempts.

It might have to do something with `iptables`, but that's where it gets a bit "foggy" for me..

Not sure how to setup a `max-three-failed-login-attempts` rule..

**Additional**: I see that the login attempts mostly have different ports for every attempt. Does that influence the count to `max-three`?

Because I see a port being "poked" twice and then no more attempts. Then the IP tries a different port (again 2 times). (all bots of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fail2ban` uses `iptables` to block (assuming you're using the default `iptables-multiport` "action" in f2b). `iptables` is just part of Linux, so isn't something you need to install.

By Ubuntu defaults, if you look in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf`, you should see something like this:

```
[ssh]

enabled  = true
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 6
```

So before we go any further, the default is 6 failed attempts before blocking, not 3. You can lower this here if you wish. That seems like it would answer your question.

But past that, check that `/etc/services` has the right port for your SSH server. I *think* this is where f2b is looking up port numbers (when you specify a port for a jail - as is above). If you are running multiple SSH servers on different ports or have multiple ports open for SSH, you might need to adjust what's being used by f2b, or remove the constraint completely.

Comment: Yes, I see now.. `maxretry` for `ssh` was still `6` (now changed to 3). But as the 'howto' adviced, I edit the file "jail.local" instead of "jail.conf" (a copy, as jail.conf can be overwritten during updates). So I have to wait and check logs again if changes were applied. Imo I have one SSH server running, but I do not completely understand your `/etc/services` part..

Comment: The port definition for the SSH jail is "ssh".. The only resolution I can see from this to an actual port number is via `/etc/services` but I'm not sure if that's what f2b uses. This might only matter if you're not running on the default port.

Comment: I just checked all three servers with `iptables -L` and several of the attacking IP's where added to the 'SSH jail'. So in my humble opinion all is working correctly after I changed the `SSH maxretry` to `3`. So, thanks for the usable and understandable answer..

Comment: @Oli: `netfilter` is a part of Linux, and it can be a module. `ipfilter` is not a part of Linux, because it lives outside the kernel - and Linux is just a kernel.

Comment: @JohnDoe: easier to get a full list with would be `iptables-save` (it prints the list of all rules, no worries, doesn't tinker with the rules like `iptables-restore` would)