# fail2ban not blocking right away

Tags: debian, ssh, putty, fail2ban

I set up a fail2ban system on my server to restrict SSH access. It works fine, except that after entering the username on the unit, if I enter the password incorrect 3 times (my maxretry value), it continues to allow the user to attempt to log in. But if I remove exit from trying to log in as that user, and open a new session, I am now banned.

When using putty, I enter the target address (but not it's username

```
login as: user
user@address's password: 1234
Access Denied
user@address's password: 1235
Access Denied
user@address's password: 1324
Access Denied
user@address's password: 1234
Access Denied
user@address's password: 1235
Access Denied
user@address's password: 1324
Access Denied
```

In theory it should not let me log in after the 3rd try, but instead it lets me go through 6 tries, after which I get a popup about having too many authentication failures. If I then go back, fail2ban has properly blocked the device from access.

How can I get it set up so that I am kicked off right after the 3rd try?

Edit: I am aware of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187203/server-login-attempts-not-blocked-after-configuring-fail2ban) question. However, I believe this is different because the poster there asks why it is not blocking at all. I am more worried about why it does not block login attempts that are already in progress.

Comment: You probably need to have fail2ban in addition to adding a block run something to kill the state for any active connections.

Comment: @roaima it seems to be the same kind of question, but I don't see an answer there to "getting kicked off right after the 3rd try", in combination with thrig's comment about the active connection.

Comment: @JeffSchaller ah ok. Re-re-reading

Answer (score 1):

After some investigations on my side,

- My `iptables`-based configuration of `fail2ban` does block active sessions, including those attempting to login and those already logged in.
- My `shorewall`-based configuration of `fail2ban` does not block active sessions, but it does prevent new connection attempts.

The variation is down to the `iptables` rules used to ban traffic and the specific configuration of `fail2ban`.

Without knowing whether you're using raw `iptables` or one of the higher level abstractions (`ufw`, `shorewall`, etc.) here are some pointers:

---

**Using `iptables`**

1. In `jail.local` I have the following definitions:

   ```
   banaction = iptables-multiport
   action_ = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s]
   action = %(action_)s
   ```

   Within each rule, either don't override the default, or else have `banaction = iptables-multiport` (which is the same as the default setting).
2. Also in `jail.local` ensure the the maximum number of retries reflects your preferred policy, either as a default or per service ruleset:

   ```
   maxretries = 3
   ```
3. In `action.d/iptables-multiport.conf` ensure you have definitions like this for the Ban and Unban rules:

   ```
   actionban = iptables -I fail2ban-<name> 1 -s <ip> -j DROP
   actionunban = iptables -D fail2ban-<name> -s <ip> -j DROP
   ```

---

**Using Shorewall**

If using the Shorewall connector for `fail2ban` you would need to adjust the default rules so that Shorewall did not apply the blocks just to initial sessions, but to all traffic for the IP address.

1. In `jail.local` I have the following definitions:

   ```
   banaction = shorewall
   action_ = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s]
   action = %(action_)s
   ```

   Within each rule, either don't override the default, or else have `banaction = shorewall` (which is the same as the default setting).
2. Also in `jail.local` ensure the the maximum number of retries reflects your preferred policy, either as a default or per service ruleset:

   ```
   maxretries = 3
   ```
3. In the [Shorewall configuration file `shorewall.conf`](http://shorewall.org/blacklisting_support.htm)

   ```
   DYNAMIC_BLACKLIST=Yes
   BLACKLISTNEWONLY=No
   ```

   The `BLACKLISTNEWONLY` setting determines whether to block all connections or just new connections. You would want `No` here.

Comment: Interesting. I use ufw. Any clue about its settings?